# Does Sachiko actually hate men?

Tags: maria-sama-ga-miteru

Throughout the series, it's stated a number of times that Sachiko hates men, because both her father and grandfather had mistresses. However, in the second OVA episode, when Lillian's Yamayuri Council goes to meet the Hanadera Student Council, Sachiko seems to lose her composure and ends up fainting.

Later in the episode, she says that it was because of the heat. However, her facial expression seems more pained when they meet the Hanadera Student Council, especially when Alice goes to hug her. Also, in the next episode, she seems to be struggling while Yumi is gone.

I am wondering if Sachiko actually hates men, or if there is something else that is causing her to look like she's in pain.